# Given a bluepring, how do I match dimensions?

Tags: inkscape

I have a blueprint with dimensions for my home. I'd like to find what the distance is from the right side of the window to the vertical dashed (blue) line to the right.

Since it shows what the distance is between the edge of the wall and the window (4'-6 3/8"), and given that a 1/4" = 1'-0", I figure there may be an easy way to let Inkscape figure out distances from there?

[image]

Comment: Your not supposed to measure out of technical drawings.

Comment: Inkscape has a measure tool, but that's about as complicated as it gets. It's not CAD software. It can't "figure out" anything.  You probably shouldn't rely on software to measure something like this from an image. It's probably not accurate enough.  Also this isn't a graphic design question, so I'm voting to close it as off-topic. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the crude approach works...

I converted 4'- 6 3/8" to centimeters (138) and then matched the lines to that on the ruler. Then got the number for the blue line (62). There may be a better approach, but it's close enough.

[image]